# Is there any way to use a second Layout with the parent Layout for specific controller?

Tags: razor, asp.net-core-mvc

How can I use a second Layout with the parent Layout for a specific controller.
In a ASP.NET MVC app we have a parent Layout for all the view

## _ViewStart

```
@{
    Layout = "_Layout";
 }
```

now I have Controller call `XcxController` and for all the view of `XcxController` I want to use another layout called `XcxLayout` with the parent `Layout`.

Is it possible? How can I achieve that?

Comment: You need to explain what do you mean by using a Layout with the parent Layout. Layouts by the name they usually work independently calling specific views.

Comment: If you don't understand my easy question then I'm feeling sorry for you.

Comment: Three days ago I commented in your post for better explanations. For what I know there is no 'Layout for a specific controller' like you sad. I am sorry that you are feeling sorry for me, but to be honest I am not feeling the same for you. So @Sabir I wish happy coding.

Comment: There is no but I need one, That's why I asked the question.

Comment: I see you found what you need @Sabir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use multiple nested Layouts including a layout within your layout:

**Index.cshtml:**

```
@{ 
    Layout = "_Layout";
}
<h1>This is normal index page</h1>
```

---

**Layout.cshtml:**

```
<h2>with normal layout</h2>
@RenderBody()
```

---

**PageWithNestedLayout.cshtml:**

```
@{
    Layout = "_NestedLayout";
}
<h1>This is another page</h1>
```

---

**_NestedLayout.cshtml:**

```
@{
    Layout = "_Layout";
}
<h2>with a nested layout and:</h2>
@RenderBody()
```